# Fitbit OAuth 2.0 and Unity Project (RestSharp as well)

Tags: unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I've been trying to get OAuth 2.0 to work correctly. I have managed to make the url that that will do the "deny/allow" for my app by opening a webpage with just

```
Application.OpenUrl(uri.ToString());
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get the redirect and the auth token from the page if the user hits allow. When you hit allow, right now nothing happens it just sits on the page. Checking Networking in chrome debug does have the redirect and token there but it never actually sends it..

I was recommended to use RestSharp but I again have no idea how to use it with Unity as there are lot of resources for Android/iOS PC etc. but I can't get any of them to work for this Unity project...

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=*clientID*&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FfitRPGcallback&scope=activity%20profile%20sleep%20social");

Debug.Log("client made");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = ("profile%20sleep%20social");

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { Debug.Log("response is : " + response.Content);});
Application.OpenURL(client.BaseUrl.ToString());
```

In the URL I do have the correct clientID in there as well just not sure what I can and can't show for security reasons etc.

Biggest problem is just having no idea how to get the return value from the webpage after the user hits allow/deny...

Any insights would be super super appreciated cause I just want to start making the actual game but there's not as much point if I can't get this data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm posting on a few other applicable questions as well since I have finally figured out my answer.

Unfortunately I'm not using REST so that part is still up in the air BUT I did get it to work with just Fitbit, Unity and a Webview plugin (you will need a webview OR a way to get the initial code back from your first OAuth2 call)

You can find steps here.

http://technicalartistry.blogspot.nl/2015/07/oauth2-unity-and-month-of-cursing.html

EDIT:

So I had to change how I did it because Fitbit changed their ToS where we are no longer allowed to use Webview based Authenticators (which is what I was using in the above blogpost.)
Give this next post a look for how to make an Android Plugin that will grab the Accesstoken from Fitbit's OAuth. This is a FREE way to do it since you make it yourself and it's ezmode :)
http://technicalartistry.blogspot.ca/2016/01/fitbit-unity-oauth-2-and-native.html